# Can scaffold-dbcontext add ConcurrencyCheck attribute?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I have used scaffold-dbcontext in Visual Studio 2017 to generate my entity framework classes from an existing database and all worked correctly.  However, on one field, I wish to maintain a concurrency check.  Is there anyway I can get scaffold-dbcontext to add the [ConcurrencyCheck] attribute to a field?

I can add the attribute manually to the property, however, if I run scaffold-dbcontext again to pick up changes to my database schema, the attribute is removed.

Comment: As I know, you can't do that because scaffolding doesn't have a way to handle of code generation

Comment: Make the database colum rowversion (timestamp) ?

Comment: As @EricEJ mentioned, if your column is of type rowversion the code generator will add an IsRowVersion property to OnModelCreating. I tried to get a ConcurrencyCheck attribute and failed, but the IsRowVersion does the trick anyway.

Comment: The trick I use for the problem of overwriting the code is to create the code in a 'raw' version, and then inherit from that for the version used by higher layers of code. This allows me to overload OnModelCreating and poke in the properties that the code generator misses.